# como ignorar el ssr en un directorio, nextjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, next.js, quill

Estoy tratando de usar debidamente el paquete "react-quill" en nextjs, el paquete funciona bien hasta que hago uso de un plugin del mismo paquete llamado ImageResize.
Cuando agrego el plugin en proyecto me empieza a arrojar un error de webpack

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que he leido sobre este problema es que: nextjs aplica ssr y debo deshabilitar ssr para ese directorio particular, este mismo paquete lo he usado con reactjs y no me da problema alguno hasta que trato de usarlo en nextjs

Como puedo deshabilitar o corregir este problema?
he tratado de configurar webpack en nextconfig.js pero no funciona, tambien he probado agregando exclude en jsconfig.json

Gracias de antemano.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso puedes usar [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr) sin SSR. Ese enlace a los docs es exactamente el código que necesitas emplear pero importando tu componente `Editor` por ejemplo.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
 
const Editor = dynamic(() => import('../components/editor-con-image-resize'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

Y nada más lo ejecutas normal como cualquier componente de React.

```js
<Editor />
```

PD: en `../components/editor-con-image-resize` por supueto que debes poner la ruta a tu componente del editor.